# Trabajar con la respuesta de una notificación Push API

Tags: javascript, push-notification

Estoy trabajando con push notifications y Push API. Desde mi archivo sw.js, obtengo el valor de la respuesta que el usuario marca en la notificación. Lo que quiero es poder trabajar con este valor de la respuesta en mis otros archivos js, pero no sé como pasar de un dato a otro.

En mi archivo **sw.js** tengo:

```
var cacheName = 'kelvin-cache';
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '../index.html',
  '../styles/css/main.css',
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
   console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
   e.waitUntil(
      caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

 self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true }).then(
        response => {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
     })
  );
});

var mood;

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
   if (e.action === 'Happy') {
       mood = "happy";
       console.log(mood)
   } else if (e.action === 'Sad') {
      mood = "sad";
      console.log(mood)
  }
});
```

Cuando el usuario vota desde la notificación, el valor de la variable mood cambia. Quiero trabajar con el valor de la variable mood en otros archivos, los enlazados en el index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"> 
</script>
<script src="src/main.js"></script>
<script src="src/client.js"></script>
<script src="src/initServiceWorker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si tu variable es global, puede ser utilizada por otros archivos, simplemente tiene que ser declarada antes que el resto.

Answer (score 1):

Los Service Workers no tienen objeto `window` el objeto global (como ya sabes puesto que lo estás usando es `self`. Pero aunque tiene limitaciones (los Service Workers no tienen acceso al DOM), `self` *mapea* a `window`, con lo que si en tu service worker usas

```
self.mood=...
```

En el resto de archivos podrás leerlo con

```
window.mood
```

El problema en este caso puede ser de coordinación, quizá sería conveniente usar eventos `message` para comunicarte